How to process OLE drag-and-drop data when formats are non-standard etc.?
I have implemented OLE drag-and-drop receiver (C++, Visual Studio 2019).
I have experimented with dragging a selected text from MS Word, or a letter from MS Outlook to the receiver window.
I have got pDataObject (IDataObject*).
The format of data is TYMED_ISTREAM.

When I was enumerating OLE formats via IEnumFORMATETC, I have got non-standard TYMED codes,
for example: 49165 with type = TYMED_ISTREAM when dragging a text from MS Word,
or 49763 when dragging a letter from MS Outlook.

How can i get info about details of these formats ?

When I was reading from the stream (49165, 49763), it first Read() has returned res_read = S_OK, but ActuallyRead == 0;
Why it can occurs (ActuallyRead == 0) ?
Does it mean the stream is empty (but I see that dragged object exists...) ?

// Stream is IStream* -- initialized, not NULL

const int BufferSize = 100000;
char* BufferPtr = (char* ) malloc(BufferSize);
if (BufferPtr == nullptr)
    return;

HRESULT res_read = Stream->Read(BufferPtr, BufferSize, &ActuallyRead);


You should just ignore formats you don't understand.

@Raymond Chen, I want to know about them! Also I don't understand, why my ActuallyRead is zero if I had dragged something. I still expected some data will be read...

You can call GetClipboardFormatName to see what the format's name is. Of course, that still might not be enough to interpret it. It could be a private format that you aren't meant to use. (And maybe the empty stream is intentional.)

The problem №2 is solved!
I had to call Stream->Seek(pos:=zero) before calling 1-st Stream->Read.
After Seek() the first Read returned non-zero ActuallyRead value.
